# Take a look at the result of Kalman filter tracking. Why is it wrong?

Tags: object, filter, tracking, video-processing, kalman-filter

When I ran the file kalman.m in from this tutorial

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14243-2d-target-tracking-using-kalman-filter

Here are the result

http://www.flickr.com/photos/58590696@N07/5375929588/
http://www.flickr.com/photos/58590696@N07/5375929552/
http://www.flickr.com/photos/58590696@N07/5375329235/

in which the green circular shows the real position of the the ball (before apply Kalman filter) and the red circular shows the estimate position of the ball (after apply Kalman filter). The result shows that using Kalman filter is worse than not using Kalman filter.

Why?

Comment: Why do you keep producing duplicates of your own questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749084/use-kalman-filter-to-track-the-position-of-an-object-but-need-to-know-the-positi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713379/question-on-tracking-a-moving-ball-using-kalman-filter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706948/why-do-we-need-to-estimate-the-true-position-in-kalman-filters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750890/please-explain-what-is-the-use-of-kalman-filter-in-this-tutorial

Comment: i did not duplicate. My questions are different but somebody may not understand my questions and keep on explain about kalman filter.